# Открытие новой вкладки по нажатию на submit

Tags: php, javascript, html5

Есть форма с двумя кнопками: **Сохранить** и **Предварительный просмотр**.
Вопрос в том, как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку **Предварительный просмотр** открывалась новая вкладка? В эту новую вкладку будут передаваться данные из формы методом `post`.

Comment: `<form target="_blank" ...`

Comment: В этом случае будет окрываться новая вкладка и по нажатию на кнопку сохранить, а нужно чтоб открывалась новая вкладка ТОЛЬКО по нажатию на кнопку предварительный просммотр!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
function clickPreview() {
  document.getElementById("actionName").value = "PREVIEW";
  var form = document.getElementById("formId");
  form.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
  form.submit();
}
function clickSave() {
  document.getElementById("actionName").value = "SAVE";
  var form = document.getElementById("formId");
  form.removeAttribute("target");
  form.submit();
}
</script>

<form id="formId" ...>

  <input type="hidden" id="actionName" name="actionName" />
  <button type="button" onclick="clickPreview()">Preview</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="clickSave()">Save</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо работает, а как в этом же скрипте передать в php атрибут name кнопки preview? И тут же вопрос как форму определить по id? Может ошибаюсь но можно ли вместо forms[0] написать form('#form')

Comment: И еще форма при таком javascript ничего не делает а только перезагружается страница. получается что не отправляется атрибут name у кнопок и форма просто не знает что делать

Comment: @privetsh - см. изменения в ответе

Comment: Не знаю по чему но не работает этот вариант

Comment: @privetsh что я могу на это сказать? Работает - это Вы неправильно код скопировали.

Comment: Я имел ввиду новую вкладку по прежнему открывает но не получает данные

Comment: @privetsh это тоже не слишком много, но хоть что-то :). Как Вы сервере получаете эти данные?

Comment: Все как обычно, простая форма с методом пост, кнопки написал из Вашего сарипта, на php просто проверяю if (isset($_POST['preview'])) { вывожу все данные из формы в предпросмотр }

Comment: @privetsh `if ($_POST['actionName'] == 'PREVIEW') { ...`

Comment: Вот я идиот и тормоз, а сам до этого не мог додуматься?! Капец, мне аж стыдно! Ладно в java  не силен, но это-то ... капец... спасибо Вам!!!

Comment: @privetsh Не расстраивайтесь :). Успехов в программировании!

Answer (score 1):

Не соответствует стандарту, но поддерживается всеми браузерами:

```
<form target="_blank">
```